# Java Circular Linked List,Remove Node not working properly

Tags: java, adt, nodes, circular-list

Ok so i need to deleted items from a circular list,as part of a bigger program that isnt working, and i cant seem to delete the last node passed in to the delete method, if the index passed in is 1 it will delete the 1st node in list and replace it, but when there is only one node left it has nothing to reference off, been at this hours. i will leave my delete method here

```
 public void delete(int index)
 {
     if(Node.numOfUsers == 1) 
     {
         first=null;
         return;
     }

     //make curr the same as first node
     int i = 1;
     curr=first;
     //if index passed in is 1, make temporary node same as one after first node
//   if(size<1)
    // {

        // System.out.println("ok so this is where we are at");
    // }
     if(index==1)
     {
         temp=first.nextNode;

         while(temp.nextNode!=first)
         {
             temp=temp.nextNode;
         }

         temp.nextNode=temp.nextNode.nextNode;
         first=curr.nextNode;
     }
     else
     {
         //as long as i is not equal to node index-1 move current on 1 and increment i by 1
         while(i != index-1)
         {
             curr=curr.nextNode;
             i++;
         }
         //curr.nextNode is pointing to the node index we want and making it equal to one index above it
         curr.nextNode=curr.nextNode.nextNode;
     }
     Node.numOfUsers--;
     int size=size();


 }
```

}

Comment: You have to treat it as a special case. If the list is empty then set a flag or make a pointer null instead of pointing to a list item. You are lucky really, with a circular linked list there is only one special case, with non circular linked lists you have more than one (first and last element operations).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're keeping track globally of a number of users. If this behaves the way I think it would, you could just have a small check at the beginning of this method so that if it is zero, you don't follow through with any of the logic following it.

```
if(Node.numOfUsers == 0) return;
```

This will make it so you don't bother executing any of the other logic.

A slightly better methodology to this problem might be to use the Node you want to delete as a parameter, rather than its index. This way you can avoid having to keep track of indices inside your data structure.
e.g.

```
public void delete(Node n) {
    if(Node.numOfUsers == 0 || n == null) return; // 0 nodes or null parameter.

    Node temp = first;

    if(temp.next == null) { //only one node
        temp = null; //simply delete it
    } else {
        while(temp.next != n) {
            temp = temp.next;
            if(temp == first) { //if we circle the entire list and don't find n, it doesn't  exist.
                return;
            }
        }
        temp.next = n.next; // perform the switch, deleting n
    }
}
```

EDIT: The above code follows the assumption that you'll have references to the node you want to delete. If this is not the case, using indices is just as good. You may also consider comparing values, however this would require you to assume that you have unique values in your nodes (and I don't know what you're restrictions are).

The logic for comparing values would be identical to the above, however instead of comparing `if(temp == n)` for example, you would compare `if(temp.data.equals(n.data))`. The use of the `.equals()` method is specifically for the `String` type, but you could modify it to work with whatever data type you are expecting, or better yet write a custom `.equals` method that allows the use of Generics for your abstract data type.

Comment: This makes sense to me but how do i pass the node into the method?

                LinkedList list = new LinkedList();
  list.add("mick o gorman");
  list.add("cathal moore");
  list.add("ciaran keyes");
  list.add("vinny crowley");

  list.size();
  list.delete(1);
  list.size();
  list.delete(1);
  list.size();
  list.delete(1);
  list.size();
  list.delete(1);  
  list.size();

I was passing in indexes but what would i put in the brackets if the nodes aren't all named

Comment: I assumed you would have access to the Node you would want to pass. If this is not correct, using indices will still work, but I would consider this methodology cleaner. For example if you had Node n = new Node("ABC"); and you placed this node into your data structure, you could delete it so long as you have a reference to n. If this is not the case in your program, than feel free to use indices (or possibly comparing the values that the node contains)

Comment: @MickO'Gorman Please see my updated answer, and accept if this solves your problem.

Comment: ok so if i go with the indices and i say if(Node.numOfUsers == 1) {What can i put in here that will delete the last node}

Comment: To delete the last node just set it equal to null, and set Node.numOfUser--; to be equal to 0. This way, any data stored inside the node is erased (the instance of the Node object is set to null, and is gone)

Comment: would you mind if i edit my question and uploaded my 3 classes?

Comment: If you're still having difficulties, go ahead.

Comment: Ok there we go, ive got so lost at this stage heads all over the place,been at this thing since yesterday morning haha, the idea is to create a list of users and the program will ask them if they want to log off, which will be randomly selected by a boolean, if they are then i send them to the delete method

Comment: Sorry mate i think I may have it sorted from your help, plus that code i uploaded is all over the place.Thanks a million

Comment: No problem, please press the check mark to accept the answer as the solution to your problem. Glad I could help!

Comment: Fancy trying this one :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33402934/java-circular-linked-list-deleting-inconsistencies