# Java Circular Linked list, Deleting inconsistencies

Tags: java, adt, nodes, circular-list

Ok so the idea for me is to be moving to each node(user in this case) in a circular list and asking if they would like to log off,they will give a random yes or no answer,until everyone has logged off. this seems to be the case most of the time i run the program but sometimes users are logging back on which shouldn't happen,I will post the delete method and the display method i am using.

```
public void displayLinkedList() {
     temp=first;
     int i = 1;

        do {
             boolean rand=randomBoolean();

             if(rand) {
                 System.out.println("USER : "+temp.data+" Logged off ");
                 temp.isloggedOut=true;
                 Node placeholder = temp.nextNode; //save value of temp.next before we delete temp
                 delete(temp);
                 Node.numOfUsers--;
                 temp = placeholder; //reassign "temp" to the appropriate next value.

             } else if(!temp.isloggedOut) {
                 System.out.println("USER : "+temp.data+" Logged on ");
                 temp=temp.nextNode; 
             }

         } while(Node.numOfUsers!=0);

    }


             public void delete(Node n) {
                    if(Node.numOfUsers == 0 || n == null) return; // 0 nodes or null parameter.

                    Node temp = first;

                    if(temp.nextNode == null) { //only one node
                        temp = null; //simply delete it
                    } else {
                        while(temp.nextNode != n) {
                            temp = temp.nextNode;
                            if(temp == first) { //if we circle the entire list and don't find n, it doesn't  exist.
                                return;
                            }
                        }
                        temp.nextNode = n.nextNode; // perform the switch, deleting n
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is in this line

```
else if(!rand)
```

Add a boolean that checks if the user has been deleted

```
else if(!rand && !userExists)
```

Comment: To make a userExists method I would have to go and name all my nodes?

Comment: @MickO'Gorman Good question.  You may just be able to use the hashcode for the object when it is created.  See https://tldrify.com/c6m

Answer (score 0):

In the above code, you reference the `temp` variable AFTER deleting it from this list. This is likely causing some problems. Adjust to be the code below.

```
    do {
         boolean rand=randomBoolean();

         if(rand) {
             System.out.println("USER : " + temp.data + " Logged off ");

             Node placeholder = temp.next; //save value of temp.next before we delete temp
             delete(temp);
             Node.numOfUsers--;
             temp = placeholder; //reassign "temp" to the appropriate next value.
         } else {
             System.out.println("USER : " + temp.data + " Logged on ");
             temp = temp.nextNode; 
         }

     } while(Node.numOfUsers != 0);
```

Also, fun fact. Theres no need to do `else if(!rand)` in the code you originally posted. By having your first case as `if(rand)` the only time this is true is when `rand == true` right? So the only other logical case is that `rand == false`, so there is no need to even have a second `if` statement checking this, because we know it can't be anything else.

Comment: Just done that, I thought it  was working for a few goes but then the last time i tried one of the users logged back on, I am just trying it with 4 users added

Comment: The reason you're getting inconsistencies is because rand is random. SOMETIMES it will print "Logged on" by chance, because you've enforced no other checks. Consider adding a Boolean variable to your node class, "isLoggedOut", you could then say "else if(!temp.isLoggedOut)" for when they're logged in, and get reliable results. Be sure to switch the value to false upon deletion from the linked list as well.

Comment: Ok going to try that now, i thought that once i deleted a node from the list i wouldn't need to worry about it coming back through the process to be logged on rather than logged out.

Comment: It's merely for good design. Have you verified that your delete method works 100%

Comment: ok i done that, but this time after a few goes i got someone logged off twice, im pretty sure i checked the delete method earlier

Comment: but now i am thinking that if an item was deleted it shouldn't come back through again, edited my question to what i have now for display method

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Modify your delete method so it works in all cases. Test it carefully on a variety of different (but simple) input.

Comment: actually since i changed the delete method to accepting nodes, im finding it hard to test, how can i try deleting them if they are not named, i was looking at the hashcode thing the other user was talking about there?

Comment: To test, manually create say 3-4 nodes (keep references to each, e.g. "Node a = new Node("A"); Node b = new Node("B"); etc. then just add each to the list, then try delete(B) and then print the list to confirm that "B" does not appear. If it does then there is a problem. Try deleting a middle element, the first element, and the last element. Also try on an empty (or null) value.